# Best practice of using SetInterval without classes in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

As part of my React learning, I wrote a simple timer. After the timer reaches the end (with `useEffect`)  it doesn't enter the function `buttonString` after the `useEffect` hook, because the `measurement` isn't part of the application state, so the HTML isn't rendered.

What is the correct way to handle such a situation? Inserting the `setInterval`'s id to a hook sounds me incorrect, but I'm not sure.

Thank you

The code:

```
var measurement;
export default function App() {
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState("10000");
  useEffect(() => {
    if (timeLeft<500) {
      clearInterval(measurement);
      measurement = null;
    } 
  }); 

  function buttonString() {
    console.log('[buttonString] measurement:' + measurement);
    return ((measurement!==null) && (measurement!==undefined)) ? "reset" : "Click To Start";
  }

  function timeLeftAsString() {    
    let duration = moment.duration(timeLeft);
    let mins = duration.minutes();
    let secs = duration.seconds();        

    return mins + " : " + secs;
  }  

  function startMeasurement() {
    clearInterval(measurement);
    var timeStart = moment().add(11, 's');
    measurement = setInterval(() => {
      setTimeLeft(moment(timeStart).diff());
      }, 500);    
    }       


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p> {timeLeftAsString()} </p>
      <Button variant="primary" size="lg" className="Button" onClick={() => {
        startMeasurement();
      }}>
        {buttonString()}
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Start any `setTimeout`/`setInterval` from within an effect hook, and return a cleanup function to `clearTimeout`/`clearInterval`.

Comment: Thx @DrewReese. 
So, there is no way to call it directly from the button click function? (=only with a boolean that the button will change its state, and will trigger the effect hook)